# How to update DDB to ONDEMAND when having more than one index

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have Table with 2 secondary index and trying to update billing mode to provisioned.
below is the aws cli used. getting error
when calling the UpdateTable operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: ProvisionedThroughput must be specified for index: gsi-key-first

```
aws dynamodb update-table \
    --table-name ddb-test-table \
    --billing-mode PROVISIONED \
    --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=15,WriteCapacityUnits=10 \
    --global-secondary-index-updates file://gsi-updates.json \
    --region us-east-1

cat gsi-updates.json

[{
    "Update": {
        "IndexName": "gsi-key-first",
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 150,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 150
        }
    },
    "Update": {
        "IndexName": "gsi-key-second",
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 150,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 150
        }
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update your gsi-updates.json like this and give it a shot:

```
[
  {
    "Update": {
      "IndexName": "gsi-key-first",
      "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 150,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 150
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Update": {
      "IndexName": "gsi-key-second",
      "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 150,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 150
      }
    }
  }
]
```

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateTable.html for more details.